# Erro minha PROCEDURE

Tags: mysql

Saúde e Paz para todos.
Por favor, tenho uma tabela tb_feriados_datas_tipo_procedure, que estou estudando.
As colunas tb_feriados_datas_tipo_procedure tem:

```
feriados_id         int(11) AUTO_INCREMENTO
nomes_feriados      varchar(255)
data_feriado        date
dia_semana_feriado  varchar(255)
```

Gostaria que o resultado povoasse as colunas data_feriado com todas as datas do ano 2021 com os respectivos dia_semana_feriado.

Criei a PROCEDURE:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE adicionar_data_feriado(
        IN data_feriado DATE, 
        IN dia_semana_feriado VARCHAR(255),        
)

BEGIN
DECLARE var_data DATE;
DECLARE var_dia VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE contador INT DEFAULT;
SET var_data = data_feriado;
SET var_dia = DAYNAME(data_feriado);
WHILE contador < intervalo DO
    INSERT INTO tb_feriados_datas_tipo_procedure(data_feriado, dia_semana_feriado)VALUES
(var_data, var_dia);
    SET contador = contador + 1;
    SET var_data = DATA_ADD(data_feriado, INTERVAL contador DAY);
    SET var_dia = DAYNAME(var_data);
    END WHILE;
    
    END;   
    DELIMITER;
```

Resultado Erro:
1 erros foram encontrados durante análise.

Mensagens do MySQL : Documentação

> ```
> #1064 - Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a ')
> ```

```
BEGIN
DECLARE var_data DATE;
DECLARE var_dia VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE conta' na linha 4
```

Comment: O que vem a ser `intervalo`? Aqui: `DECLARE contador INT DEFAULT;` não falta nada?

Comment: DECLARE contador INT DEFAULT; já está declarado. Conferi e não encontrei nada faltando. O que não informei foi que na ultima linha DELIMITER; tem uma indicação em vermelho mostrando que ali existe uma erro. Não consigo criar a PROCEDURE.

Comment: Após `DEFAULT` não precisa ser informado um valor? Você utiliza `intervalo` sem definir.